# How does DATEADD work when joining the same table with itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dateadd

I have a table with monthly production values.

Example:

```
Outdate | Prod Value | ID
2/28/19 |      110   | 4180
3/31/19 |      100   | 4180
4/30/19 |      90    | 4180
```

I also have a table that has monthly forecast values.

Example:

```
Forecast End Date | Forecast Value  | ID
2/28/19           |   120           | 4180
3/31/19           |   105           | 4180
4/30/19           |    80           | 4180
```

I want to create a table that has a row that contains the ID, the Prod Value, the current month (example: March) forecast, the previous month forecast, the next month forecast.

What I want:

```
ID | Prod Value | Outdate | Current Forecast | Previous Forecast | Next Forecast
4180 | 100      | 3/31/19 |              105 |               120 | 80
```

The problem is that when I used `DATEADD` to bring in the specific value from the Forecast table for the previous month, random months are missing from my final values.

I've tried adding in another `LEFT JOIN` / `INNER JOIN` with the DateDimension table when adding in the Next Month and Previous Month forecast, but that either does not solve the problem or adds in too many rows.

My DateDimension table that has these columns: DateKey
Date, Day, DaySuffix, Weekday, WeekDayName, IsWeekend, IsHoliday, DOWInMonth, DayOfYear, WeekOfMonth, WeekOfYear, ISOWeekOfYear, Month, MonthName, Quarter, QuarterName, Year, MMYYYY, MonthYear, FirstDayOfMonth, LastDayOfMonth, FirstDayOfQuarter, LastDayOfQuarter, FirstDayOfYear, LastDayOfYear, FirstDayOfNextMonth, FirstDayOfNextYear

My query is along these lines (abbreviated for simplicity)

```
SELECT A.ArchiveKey, BH.ID, d.[Date], BH.Outdate, BH.ProdValue, BH.Forecast, BHP.Forecast, BHN.Foreceast
FROM  dbo.BudgetHistory bh 
INNER JOIN dbo.DateDimension d ON bh.outdate = d.lastdayofmonth 
INNER JOIN dbo.Archive a ON bh.ArchiveKey = a.ArchiveKey 
LEFT JOIN  dbo.BudgetHistory bhp ON bh.ID = bhp.ID AND bhp.outdate = DATEADD(m, - 1, bh.Outdate) 
LEFT JOIN  dbo.BudgetHistory bhn ON bh.ID = bhn.ID AND bhn.outdate = DATEADD(m, 1, bh.Outdate)
WHERE        bh.ID IS NOT NULL
```

I get something like this:

```
+------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+
|  ID  | Prod Value | Outdate | Current Forecast | Previous Forecast | Next Forecast |
+------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 4180 |        110 | 2/28/19 |              120 | NULL              | NULL          |
| 4180 |        100 | 3/31/19 |              105 | 120               | 80            |
| 4180 |        90  | 4/30/19 |              80  | NULL              | NULL          |
+------+------------+---------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

And the pattern doesn't seem to follow anything reasonable. 
I want the values to be filled in for each row.

Comment: So.  Does the BudgetHistory table store both the ProdValue and the Forecast?  What is the Archive table?  Creating the structures with values in SQLFiddle would be a great way to get help.  @GMB's answer below would work but I am having trouble seeing why yours wouldn't.  His is more elegant but yours should work unless I am missing something, which is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could join the tables, then use window functions `LEAD()` and `LAG()` to recover the next and previous forecast values:

```
SELECT
    p.ID,
    p.ProdValue,
    p.Outdate,
    f.ForecastValue,
    LAG(f.ForecastValue) OVER(PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY f.ForecastEndDate) PreviousForecast,
    LEAD(f.ForecastValue) OVER(PARTITION BY f.ID ORDER BY f.ForecastEndDate) NextForecast
FROM prod p
INNER JOIN forecast f ON p.ID = f.ID AND p.Outdate = f.ForecastEndDate
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d824b1195f5705b80171ea1b3d57782)** with your sample data returns:

```
  ID | ProdValue | Outdate             | ForecastValue | PreviousForecast | NextForecast
---: | --------: | :------------------ | ------------: | ---------------: | -----------:
4180 |       110 | 28/02/2019 00:00:00 |           120 |             null |          105
4180 |       100 | 31/03/2019 00:00:00 |           105 |              120 |           80
4180 |        90 | 30/04/2019 00:00:00 |            80 |              105 |         null
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` only does end of month adjustments if the newly calculated value isn't a valid date. So `DATEADD(month,-1,'20190331')` produces 28th February. But `DATEADD(month,-1,'20190228')` produces 28th January, *not* the 31st.

I would probably go with [GMB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525318/15498). If you want to do something `DATEADD` based though, you can use:

```
bhp.outdate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,'20010131', bh.Outdate) ,'20001231')
```

This always works out the last day of the previous month from `bh.OutDate`, but it does it by computing it as an *offset* from a fixed date, and then applying that offset to a different fixed date.

You can just reverse the places of `20010131` and `20001231` to compute the month after rather than the month before. There's no significance about them other than them both having 31 days and having the "one month apart" relationship we're wishing to apply.